# one possible meaning of name Ramchandra?

Tags: vishnu, rama, name

I heard it means "reflector of Brahman"

Ram means "Vishnu/Parbrahman".

Chandra - moon, thus indicating said person is reflection of god's virtues as the moon reflects sun(light).

I was told that even seventh avatar of Lord Vishnu was named for thus reason.

Comment: Are you answering your question in the body?

Comment: nope . I am asking if that is one meaning of "Ramchandra" as such ? I am asking other's opinion

Comment: It looks like you are answering your question in the body. Asking users opinion is not allowed and your question is duplicate too.